# UITableViewController used to select an object

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

Currently I have a UITableViewController with static cells which acts like a form for user input. There is one cell with a given amount of entries. This entries can be selected in another UITableViewController by clicking on the cell. Programmatically you select an object from the class "EventType". This object should be forwarded to the first UITableViewController when selecting one entry.
I am able to call the second UITableViewController and dismiss it by calling:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

My problem is that I don't know how to forward the object to the first UIViewController and afterwards I want to update the label in the cell with a property of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How do I pass the data back?**

If we want to pass the data back from SecondViewController to FirstViewController, we need to use protocols and delegates. To do this, we will have to make FirstViewController a delegate of SecondViewController. If we do this, it allows SecondViewController to send a message back to FirstViewController, thus enabling us to send data back.

If FirstViewController has to be a delegate of SecondViewController, it must conform to SecondViewController’s protocol. We have to make sure we specify the protocol correctly. This tells FirstViewController what methods it needs to implement.

In SecondViewController.h, after all the #import statements, but before the @interface line, we need to specify the protocol as given below:

```
@class SecondViewController;
@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)addItemViewController:(SecondViewController *)controller didFinishEnteringItem:(NSString *)item;
@end
```

Next, still in the SecondViewController.h, you need to setup a delegate property and synthesize in SecondViewController.m as given below:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

In SecondViewController, we call a message on the delegate when we pop the view controller.

```
NSString *itemToPassBack = @"This value is going back to FirstViewController";
[self.delegate addItemViewController:self didFinishEnteringItem:itemToPassBack];
```

That’s it for SecondViewController. Now in FirstViewController.h, tell FirstViewController to import SecondViewController and conform to its protocol.

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <SecondViewControllerDelegate>
```

In FirstViewController.m, implement the following method from our protocol:

```
- (void)addItemViewController:(SecondViewController *)controller didFinishEnteringItem:(NSString *)item
{
    NSLog(@"This was returned from SecondViewController %@",item);
}
```

Now, all we need to do is tell SecondViewController that FirstViewController is its delegate before we push SecondViewController on to navigation stack. Add the following changes in FirstViewController.m:

```
SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNib:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
secondViewController.delegate = self
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
```

And that’s it! You are now set to send data from SecondViewController to FirstViewController.

[The source](http://prateekvjoshi.com/2014/02/16/ios-app-passing-data-between-view-controllers/)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed description. It worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Welcome you, glad that helped